# IBM Cloud Functions Python API to open a local file browser to upload file

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions, watson-assistant-solutions

I'm working on a Watson Assistant chatbot that connects to IBM Cloud Functions through Python API. I want to make the chatbot open a local browser window to upload a file from local machine to save it into a database. I'm intending to do that through IBM Cloud Functions Python API.

However, I'm a bit confused on how to make the python API open a local file browser window to make the user select a file from the local machine.

Any help in that, please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Cloud Functions run on servers in the IBM Cloud. They are intended to run short(er) workloads without any user interaction.

What you are looking for is a chatbot app which calls into the Watson Assistant service. The app is a wrapper around the dialog service. It gets the user input, sends it to Watson Assistant, receives the answer and prints it for the user.

As add-on, the app could open a local file browser and send a file to Watson Assistant. Note that Watson Assistant would not know what to do with that file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Make sense.. So, as I understand there is no knind of "native" way to make the cloud service opens a local file browser in the local machine.

Comment: How should that server know about your local machine and how should it have permissions to access that machine? Scary thought, right?

Comment: Yes.. Make sense :) Thanks